# Working with Isometries in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, isometry

I know that the isometry group of  $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 
$\text{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2) = O(\mathbb{R}^2) \; T(\mathbb{R}^2) = \{h \circ g : h \in  T(\mathbb{R}^2), g\in O(\mathbb{R}^2) \}$, where $O(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the orthogonal group, and $T(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the translation group.

I want to prove that $T(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is normal in $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

---

So, I want to show that $$r \circ T_a \circ r^{-1} \in  T(\mathbb{R}^2).$$

Since all elements in $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ can be written in the form $h \circ g : h \in  T(\mathbb{R}^2), g\in O(\mathbb{R}^2) $, this is equivalent to proving that
 $$(h \circ g) \circ T_a \circ (h \circ g)^{-1} \in  T(\mathbb{R}^2) .$$

where $T_a(x) = x+a$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Conjugating by a translation clearly gives us a translation, so we will conjugate by an element $g \in O(\mathbb{R}^2) $

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, since all elements in $ \text{Isom}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ are bijections,
 $$(g \circ T_a \circ g^{-1} ) (x)$$
 $$ = ( g \circ T_a) (g^{-1} (x)) $$
 $$= g (g^{-1} (x)  +a) $$
 $$= (x)  +g(a) $$

> I am unsure of this last step. How do we know $g(x+t) = g(x) + g(t)$? What I mean is, how do we know that is isn't a homomorphism under the multiplication law, which would mean that $g(xt) = g(x) g(t)$ but wouldn't necessarily say anything about $g(x+t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isomorphism is not just an isomorphism of abstract groups, it also tells you how $(h,g)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The function $g$ is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. a matrix that multiplies vectors from the left, therefore $g(v+u) = g(v)+g(u)$.

Maybe the confusion comes from the fact, that that what you are really studying is $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{A}^2,d)$, isometries of the affine plane with a given metric $d$. Then you can embed $O(2)$ in the group of those isometries by choosing the fixed point and the axes.

But once you choose a chart $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ which respects affine structure and metric, you can see $\text{Isom}(\mathbb{A}^2,d)$ as you described it in your question.